# What Docker Command Do I Run To Show Code Changes?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

So i've been through a lot of tutorials and the docs but it isn't clear to me on how to deploy code changes.

I was given a project that utilizes Docker but I have no previous knowledge of Docker so forgive my ignorance.

I've made changes to the Python project and I've pushed those changes to the Git branch. I tried pulling those changes onto the server but the website isn't reflecting my changes. Do I need to run a docker command to make the nodes use the new code? If so, what is that command? Will that command push the code changes out to all the nodes?

I have a service that looks like:

```
services:
    myappname:
        build: .
        command: bash /directory_name/server/filename.sh
        volumes:
        - .:/another_dir_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you build and deploy new docker images with the updated code?

To get the environment to use the latest code you have to build new docker images  and deploy the new images to the environment.